# How to get value from javascript function loaded on webview in android

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I have to say that, i look up a lot but i couldn't find the answer although there are lots of answer. They did not work for me.

I have a javascript function called getCustomerID() in my website which is loaded to my webview. It just return an id value as integer.

How can i get this return value ?

Here is function loaded in webview :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getCustomerID(){
        return 0;
    }
</script>
```

And i just want to get that "0".

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: You'd just run `getCustomerID();`, wouldn't you? Maybe set a variable to its return value like so: `var x = getCustomerID();`, right? Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Actually i want to get that return value into my android activity. @TheWobbuffet

Answer (score 2):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getCustomerID(){
        window.SJSI.sendValue(0);
        return 0;
    }
</script>
```

And implement:

```
...
webView.addJavascriptInterface(new SimpleJavaScriptInterface(), "SJSI");

final class SimpleJavaScriptInterface 
{
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void sendValue(final String value) 
    {
        myvalue = value;
        ...
    }
}
```

and don't forget:

```
WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Comment: Thanks for response, but it does not work. @JanHvrda

Comment: It is weird. What is the behavior when you call the window.SJSI.sendValue(0) line - I mean javascript error or program enter the sendValue() method in Java, but value is not passed correctly or program even don't enter the sendValue() method...

Comment: Should this error be about permissions or etc ? @JanHvrda

Comment: I'm not sure - may be try to add: webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);